# exclude a method/branch from instrumentation cobertura

Tags: java, instrumentation, cobertura

I need to skip certain methods or code segments from instrumentation and code coverage. That lead me to   [Exclude methods from code coverage with Cobertura](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951569/exclude-code-from-code-coverage-with-cobertura).

Then the cobertura ant page
http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/anttaskreference.html  said 
...
 You can tell Cobertura to ignore certain classes by passing in "ignore" regular expressions. The ignore pattern can be any valid perl 5 regular expression. This will ignore any calls to any method that matches the ignore regular expression. **It will NOT skip over these classes during instrumention. To exclude classes from being instrumented, either exclude them from your fileset** or use the alternative method below and specify an excludeClasses pattern.
....

From the source code of net.sourceforge.cobertura.ant.InstrumentTask.java

```
        for (int i = 0; i < ignoreBranchesRegexs.size(); i++) {
            IgnoreBranches ignoreBranchesRegex = (IgnoreBranches)ignoreBranchesRegexs.get(i);
            builder.addArg("--ignoreBranches", ignoreBranchesRegex.getRegex());
        }
```

What does  the "--ignoreBranches" do? What is the pattern expected?  I am going to try it. If you have used above option, please share your "command line"

Answer (score 1):

Please see this link. http://svnsearch.org/svnsearch/repos/COBERTURA/search?start-index=60&
Apparently, there is an @Ignore method annotation that was added for this purpose. As for code blocks, I would try the same thing. Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to the question, but my take on it would be: "Cover it." Don't exclude things from coverage reports. Fix the coverage.

Comment: What about the branch coverage? do you imply that you write test cases for every if statement for an auto generated equals method?

Comment: @imellan: Resurrecting an old question, but still relevant. If it's code, cover it, regardless of who wrote it. A better alternative to dumb, generated code might be an equals helper like Guava [Objects.equal()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#equal(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)) or commons-lang [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html). The bottom line is: if you intend for code to do something, there better be tests expressing your intent.