# Excluding java files in sonar report through Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

I am running sonar from Jenkins. I want to exclude some java files in the sonar report. Is that possible through Jenkins? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using jenkins sonar plugin, refer to [this documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins) on how to configure the plugin to specify [additional parameters](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-patterns) which allow files to be excluded from analysis.

Comment: Both links are 404.

Answer (score 8):

Just pass the "sonar.exclusions" property to your build (for instance using a JVM argument "-Dsonar.exclusions=**/Foo.java").

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to sonar section of your jenkins job.
2. Click on advanced.
3. In **Additional properties** put or add: 
   `-Dsonar.exclusions=com/company/packageA/generated/**/*.java,com/company/packageB/generated/**/*.java`
4. Save changes.

Notice how multiple packages can be specified using commas.