# Cobertura and skipping of Java logging (isLoggable) within Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, logging, cobertura, java.util.logging

I'm currently in the process of becoming a TDD hacker. As part of this I feel that a code coverage report like the one Cobertura generates is a essential piece of tool.

But, my code coverage is somewhat bloated as the following code doesn't get covered correctly:

```
if(logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO)) {
    logger.info("blah blah blah");
}
```

I'm running the report within Jenkins and Maven (don't know is that can be a problem?). `isLoggable(Level.INFO)` is (in my case) always true thus it enters and logs. I'd like to be able to either skip the part or be able to set `isLoggable(Level.XX)` to true AND false.

Any ideas, hints etc? Maybe something I have overlooked, everything is much appreciated! :)

[edit]
Seems like a bug in the Maven cobertura plugin which should be fixed in 2.6: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOBERTURA-52
BUT 2.6 haven't been released, so I'll just have to wait...
[/edit]

Comment: Good idea, but my code wouldn't pass review :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instrument the classes you can ignore certain methods/calls. The report is a step after that.

With ant this is done like this (example from the [docs](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/anttaskreference.html)). Maven might have the same options, but this depends on the maven plugin you use.:

```
<cobertura-instrument todir="${instrumented.dir}">
    <ignore regex="java.util.logging.*" />
    <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
        ...
    </fileset>
</cobertura-instrument>
```

You simply set an ignore regex for the packages you want to have excluded from instrumentation, this way they won't show up in the reports.

With Maven this should work:

```
<instrumentation>
    <ignores>
       <ignore>java.util.logging.*</ignore>
    </ignores>
</instrumentation>
```

Comment: I'm using maven (http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/) and tried adding an ignore, but nothing happens, exclude works fine. Any ideas? Also, I'm using java.util.logging (not log4j). I know, but I'm not going to change it right now (unless that is the only way I can "fix" this).

Comment: I changed the answer to java.util.logging. I know that the ant way works therefore the maven way should work too, but I never used it with maven.

Comment: That is what I have... but it doesn't work - if I add excludes it excludes the source files (thus the instrumentation part works, only seems like ignore doesn't)...

Comment: did you -clean- before retrying?

Comment: Yeah, already have my conf in <build>. 

After doing a lot of digging I have found that v2.2 of the plugin works with ignore, but f*** everything else - v2.3 and new works fine but f***s with ignore :(

Answer (score 0):

There is nice article explaining in details how you can exclude logging calls from cobertura instrumentation.
http://fahdshariff.blogspot.gr/2010/01/cobertura-ignore-logger-calls.html
and a similar question posted here: [Exclude methods from code coverage with Cobertura](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951569/exclude-code-from-code-coverage-with-cobertura)

I think you might find useful both of these links

Comment: I have seen the blog and question, but it doesn't seem to skip them. I'm currently running with version 2.5.1, but if I roll back to 2.2 (as on the blog post) it works... A bug perhaps?