# Sonar Jacoco Excludes sonar.jacoco.excludes causes 0% coverage instead of ignored.

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

When I write

```
<sonar.jacoco.excludes>*.model.*</sonar.jacoco.excludes>
```

The package is not excluded from instrumentation / reporting and coverage shows as 0%

Why is this ?

Sonar version 3.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Common pitfall to use the wrong pattern to exclude. Notice the .

Bad :

```
<sonar.jacoco.excludes>*.model.*</sonar.jacoco.excludes>
```

Good:

```
<sonar.jacoco.excludes>*model*</sonar.jacoco.excludes>
```

Documentation for weary travellers.

Comment: How do you exclude specifc packages and files such as all the java files in one package?

Comment: it's outdated. see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135939/how-to-make-sonar-ignore-some-classes-for-codecoverage-metric/27133765#27133765

Answer (score 6):

I am using SonarQube version 4.5 and setting **sonar.coverage.exclusions** property worked in my case. Official documentation is [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreCodeCoverage).

In your case I suggest to use the following property

```
sonar.coverage.exclusions=**/model/**/*
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using sonarqube 10.3.0 and able to ignore the classes in code coverage report
using below

```
<sonar.exclusions>src/main/java/com/<entire_package>/repository/*>
</sonar.exclusions>
<sonar.exclusions>src/main/java/com/<entire_package>/SpringbootWebfluxApplication*>
</sonar.exclusions>
```

here all classes under repository has been ignored and SpringbootWebfluxApplication class is igonred. Also noticed that only giving core package in exclusion does not work. For example below did not worked

```
<sonar.exclusions>com/<entire_package>/SpringbootWebfluxApplication*></sonar.exclusions>
```

where as in case of jacoco, below exclusion worked perfectly fine.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>com/<entire_package>/reposity/*</exclude>                      
            <exclude>
                com/<entire_package>/SpringbootWebfluxApplication.java
            </exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>        
</plugin>
```

Find more details [here](https://groups.google.com/g/sonarqube/c/VwEE_ZD2KzI)