# Sonar showing issue for private fields of DTO class

Tags: java, json, sonarqube

I have this DTO class:

```
class DTO{
    private String a;

    public DTO(String a){
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

I am JSON serializing this class using Gson and sending it over to other application.

I don't need getters for this class. For this class sonar is showing following issue:

```
"Remove this unused "a" private field."
```

Should I ignore this sonar issue or there is another ideal way to change my code to eliminate this sonar error?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135939/how-to-make-sonar-ignore-some-classes-for-codecoverage-metric to exclude some code coverage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue raised by SonarQube is a false positive in this example.
Your best course of action is to mark it as such on SonarQube.

If your DTO files follow a consistent naming pattern,
then it could also be interesting to configure SonarQube to ignore this issue in those files by default.

Comment: The  documentation link is  no more  accessible, feel free to amend/delete it

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent SonarQube false positives for your DTOs you could use [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) as a library to create DTOs:

```
@AutoValue
@AutoGson(autoValueClass = AutoValue_DTO.class)
public abstract class DTO
{
    public abstract String getA();
}
```

with AutoGson defined as:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface AutoGson
{
    Class autoValueClass();
}
```

and a Gson type adapter defined as:

```
public class AutoValueTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type)
    {
        Class<? super T> rawType = type.getRawType();

        AutoGson annotation = rawType.getAnnotation(AutoGson.class);
        if (annotation == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return (TypeAdapter<T>) gson.getAdapter(annotation.autoValueClass());
    }
}
```

which is used by Gson as:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new AutoValueTypeAdapterFactory())
```

Comment: this seems like adding too much complexity just to resolve sonar cube issue.