# cobertura ant task: exclude certain classes

Tags: ant, code-coverage, cobertura

Is it possible to exclude/bypass certain classes in a cobertura coverage-check Ant task? i.e., the if certain  classes have coverage lesser than the specified limit then the build should not fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can exclude certain classes by name, using `fileset`:

```
<cobertura-instrument todir="${instrumented.dir}">
  <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
     <exclude name="**/*Test.class" />
  </fileset>
</cobertura-instrument>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951670/2294676).